# How can I run shortcode after click with ajax

Tags: shortcode, ajax, google-maps, tabs

I have a little problem and need your help. I have tabs on my page and in one tab i have google maps. This tab is hidden by default and when i clik on it, i can see only small piece of maps. Map it is shortcode from one installed plugin. I found solution how to run ajax request ([here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140086/execute-a-shortcode-when-clicking-on-a-image)) to load content after click  and it looks like working right with simple html code, but when I try place php code with shortcode it doesn't work. I think it is simple but my knowledge is too small to write working code :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#map').on('click',function() {
        var data = {
            action: 'process_shortcode_on_tab_click'
        }
        $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',data).done(function(response) {    
             $('#map-containter').html('<?php echo do_shortcode("[map_shortcode height='300']"); ?>');   
        });
    })
})
```

```
<div class="tabs">
<a class="tab active" href="#">Tab 1</a>
<a class="tab" href="#">Tab 2</a>
<a id="map" class="tab" href="#">Tab with map</a>
```

And in my theme function i have this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_process_shortcode_on_tab_click_action', 'process_shortcode_on_tab_click_ajax');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_shortcode_on_tab_click_action', 'process_shortcode_on_tab_click_ajax');

function process_shortcode_on_tab_click_ajax() {
echo do_shortcode('[map_shortcode height="300"]');
die();
}
```

Comment: first check by alert..what you have got in response then put it in your html instead of shortcode..

Comment: @Priyajain Yes, you are right. You have to check `alert();` first. And please check this [execute-a-shortcode-when-clicking-on-a-image](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140086/execute-a-shortcode-when-clicking-on-a-image). If not, find me in any social network by looking `yeshansachithak`.

Comment: After answer from @birgire ajax start working but still is something wrong. Alert displays message "Undefined". After click on the tab, ajax load script from shortcode but this script created empty div="map-canvas". Normally in this div was the map content. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to replace the following jQuery part:

```
 action: 'process_shortcode_on_tab_click'
```

with this one:

```
 action: 'process_shortcode_on_tab_click_action'
```

to match your `wp_ajax_process_shortcode_on_tab_click_action` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_process_shortcode_on_tab_click_action` actions.

Check for example the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) on how to name the custom `wp_ajax_$youraction` hook.

Answer (score 0):

@birgire is correct, but there is one more thing you need to do. You don't need to call *do_shortcode()* in

```
$('#map-containter').html('<?php echo do_shortcode("[map_shortcode height='300']"); ?>');
```

because the shortcut is already ran via the function *process_shortcode_on_tab_click_ajax()*, and by this time is already stored in the AJAX response. So simply use *the response*:

```
$('#map-containter').html(response);
```

Easy peasy